# Regex does not work with input string containing + inside

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following piece of code:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/url.html";
$content=Encode::encode_utf8(get $url);

$nameaux = Encode::encode_utf8($DBfield);

if($content =~ />$nameaux<\/a><\/td><td class="class1">(.*?)<\/td>/ ||
   $content =~ />$nameaux<\/a><\/td><td class="class2">(.*?)<\/td>/ ||
   $content =~ />$nameaux<\/a><\/td><td class="class3">(.*?)<\/td>/ ) {
    ... more code ...
}
```

This piece of code works great except when `$DBfield` is equal to a string containing a plus (ex. A+1) on it that exists on `$content`.

Could someone explain my how to handle this?

Comment: If this is real code, reformat to `if($content =~ />$nameaux<\/a><\/td><td class="class\d+">(.*?)<\/td>)/`

Comment: `+` in a regex means the previous element (a character, class, group..) should appear one or more times. To match the `+` itself you will need to scape it `\+`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $nameaux can contain regex characters (like +), you need to escape the field to a regex literal by wrapping with `\Q` ... `\E`.

```
$content =~ />\Q$nameaux\E<\/a><\/td><td class="class1">(.*?)<\/td>/ ||
```

So `+` will be just a plus sign and not mean "one or more of", which is why your regex doesn't match.